# How to put numbers into vertices of the planar graph?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

I need to put numbers into vertexes $\{A, B, C, D, E, F\}$ of the planar graph (left figure), so that the sums of numbers of all five triangles were equal.

**My attempt:** I have used the `1's (red color on right figure) and sums are equal to 3 (blue color).

[image]

**Question.** Is it possible to solve this task with the different numbers?

Comment: You could change $F$ to $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observation:

$F$ can be chosen arbitrarily since it is involved in the sum of each triangle.

We need

$$A+B= B + C = C+D = D + E = E + A$$

From there we can conclude that $$A=B=C=D=E$$

We can check that that is the sufficient and necessary condition to satisfy the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Any two adjacent triangles will force a pair of numbers to be the same. For example, given triangles $BFC$ and $DFC$ you need $B + F + C = D +F+C$ and hence you need $B=D$. LIkewise you find that you need $C=E$, $D=A$, $E=B$, and $A=C$, meaning that all the five numbers on the outside have to be the same. $F$ can be different though.